# Pie Chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

I tried to google this but no luck. It is easy to add a pie chart when you have prcentace data but what if you just have a list of partially repeated data?

For simplicity imagine there is a table in Excel which represents all cars in a town. One of columns is 'color'. How is it possible to add a pie chart representing colors of cars without calculating percentage? And, it is important to mention that if comeone will add a pink or any new color car first time into the table, the pie chart should automaticaly have one more slice.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two columns:

```
Colour  Number
Red     3
Blue    5
Green   6
Purple  4
Black   10
```

Then create the pie from these it will work.

To add a new colour so it gets automatically inserted into the chart you'll need to insert a new line rather than just appending to the end.

```
Colour  Number
Red     3
Blue    5
Green   6
Purple  4
Pink    1     <-- new value inserted here.
Black   10
```

Comment: Beat me to it.

No need for percentages - they're implicit in pie charts.

Comment: These things will will require additional calculations. What I have:
Ford AAA111 Red /
Nissan BBB222 Blue /
Mini CCC333 Pink /
Alfa-Romeo DDD444 Red /
(sorry, website removes CRLFs)

Comment: @Usability victim - Update your question with this extra information.

Comment: ChrisF, what extra information do you need?

Comment: @Usability victim - what you posted as a comment, that way we'll have your real data, properly formatted, to work from.

Comment: Why do you need real data? I have posted a sample in the comment above.

Comment: @Usability victim - when I said "real" I meant "your", plus it would be correctly formatting in the question.